# Jquery data tables input calculation only works on first 10 results

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have datatables setup and working fine returning all the db records,
Im not that savvy with jquery but it got me hooked !! and im learning on the job so to speak.

My problem is  The Table renders fine the calculation for working out 
available stock, 
Qty required & 
How many back order items needed only works on the first 10 rows.
once i use the pagination the calculation stops working

please find my code below  New working code found below in case anyone else needs it

```
//loads data tables fine 
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#datatable1').dataTable();
       });


    //this works on the frist 10 rows of the table only 

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.qty').on('change', function() {
        $('.hours-table tr').each(function() {
            var qty = $(this).find('input.qty').val();
            var av = $(this).find('input.av').val();
            var dateTotal = (av - qty);
            if(qty < av ){
                $(this).find('input.bo').val('0')}
            else{
                $(this).find('input.bo').val(dateTotal);
                }
        }); //END .each
        return false;
    }); // END click 
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

New working Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#datatable1').dataTable({
     "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
  $('.qty').on('change', function() {
    $('.hours-table tr').each(function() {
        var hours = $(this).find('input.qty').val();
        var rate = $(this).find('input.av').val();
        var dateTotal = (rate - hours);
        if(hours < rate ){
            $(this).find('input.bo').val('0');}
        else{
            $(this).find('input.bo').val(dateTotal);
            }
    }); //END .each
    return false;
}); // END click 

}
```

}

```
            );
   } );
```

Comment: How is your pagination done? I'm guessing that you're using ajax and thus need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in your methods.

Comment: Many Thanks for you reply 
The pagination is handled by data tables

Comment: You could use the pagination event and fire your $('.hours-table tr') once you change the pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [**fnDrawCallback**](https://datatables.net/ref#fnDrawCallback) to execute your function.

```
$('#datatable1').dataTable({
   "fnDrawCallback":function(){
        $('.hours-table tr').each(function() {
            var qty = $(this).find('input.qty').val();
            var av = $(this).find('input.av').val();
            var dateTotal = (av - qty);
            if(qty < av ){
                $(this).find('input.bo').val('0')}
            else{
                $(this).find('input.bo').val(dateTotal);
                }
        }); //END .each
    }

});
```

This will work the first time the table is drawn and each time you change of page.

*I Added an example fiddle with a test using the fnDrawCallback*

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uHFSZ/)

Comment: Yw I was just doing an example using the callback to post it I've added it to the answer it might help you or someone in the future.